# Store a png file inside a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, png

I am making a chrome extension that will show you a button, and when you click on it a picture of a puppy randomly selected from a database, I'm trying to figure out how to store a png file in a js variable. A little help?

Comment: Image can be of two (or more) types mainly, link (short) / data-url (very long). Both of them can be stored in a `string` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply store a url location of the image and then set the variable like this.

var variableName = 'https://www.example.com/example.png';

If there is security issues calling a http method then you will need a base64 version of the image held in the database. The base64 data would be populated from your database and set to a variable in JavaScript.

var variableName = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAUhEUgAABLAAAAXcCAYAAdaAAAAAAuI....';